# How to access a vBox or any other layout from controller?

Tags: java, opencv, javafx, javafx-8, opencv3.0

What I am planning is to get live feed from my webcam using openCV on the scene. for which I am using JavaFX for GUI purposes.

GUI:
 I have parent window as a AnchorPane. In which I have added a Vbox and Hbox. where Vbox contains canvas(where the live feed is loaded).Hbox contains 2 buttons
I am taking the parent as AnchorPane. So when I run the code I get the Video feed in the whole window and  the button gets removed. So what I want is that the video feed should show in the vBox.

[image: Layout]

[image: Output]

The buttons get removed when I run the program.

- Is there any way that the video feed takes only the vBOX scene?

  *To make it clear I want those buttons to be shown during the video feed.*

In the following code I have given ID to AnchorPane(fx:id-anchorpane ) and vBOX(fx:id- vb). I tried getting the scene from vb(the comment in code) but I think I am missing something.

Code Snippet:

```
@FXML
private Canvas canvas;
@FXML
private Button button_start;
private static final int SCENE_W = 640;
private static final int SCENE_H = 480;

VideoCapture videoCapture;
GraphicsContext g2d;
@FXML
Stage stage;
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorpane;
@FXML
private VBox vb;
@FXML
private Group group;

Scene scene;
AnimationTimer timer;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    initOpenCv();
    System.out.println("test3");
    canvas = new Canvas(SCENE_W, SCENE_H);
    g2d = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    g2d.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
    group = new Group(canvas);
    scene = new Scene(group, SCENE_W, SCENE_H);
    stage = (Stage) anchorpane.getScene().getWindow();
    //stage = (Stage) vb.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
    }
    timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        Mat mat = new Mat();
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            videoCapture.read(mat);
            Image image = mat2Image(mat);
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

In the code initopenCv() function loads the native library and has the videoCapture function of OpenCV.

```
 private void initOpenCv() {

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    videoCapture = new VideoCapture();
    videoCapture.open(0);

    System.out.println("Camera open: " + videoCapture.isOpened());
}
```

Comment: Why are you re-creating the UI controls? Everything with the `@FXML` annotation should be initialized by the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: #sillyfly : I am new to JavaFX. could you please elaborate  what I am re-creating?UI controls? and any suggestion for my questions?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm  

As to your question - it is unclear to me if you use the FXML created by SceneBuilder shown in your first image. If you do, you should not need to instantiate the Group, Canvas etc.  

At any rate, you create a new `Scene` without the `VBox` in it.

Comment: In short, you should remove `canvas = new Canvas(...)` and everything from `group = new Group(...)` to `stage.show()` (inclusive) from your handler method. If that gives you null pointer exceptions, then the `fx:id`s are not set up correctly in your FXML file.